# Get latest child record without given order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, has-many

Simplified, I got the following situation. I've got two tables. One migration has multiple checks through `checks.migration_id`. The Column `checks.old` describes a type of check. Now I want to get for each migration the check with the biggest time where `old` is true (query1) and false (query2).

There are about 30.000 migrations and each has around 1000 checks where old=true and 1000 checks where old=false. The table checks will grow quite extreme. The order of the checks is not given and could be totally mixed up.

I want to get the latest check for a maximum of 150 migrations at once.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/282ce/15

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and Rails 3.2 (shouldn't matter)

**Whats the most efficient way to get the latest subrecord where old = true?**

Table Migrations:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
```

Table Checks:

```
| ID | MIGRATION_ID | OLD | OK |                             TIME |
|----|--------------|-----|----|----------------------------------|
|  1 |            1 |   1 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:01+0000 |
|  2 |            1 |   0 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:02+0000 |
|  3 |            2 |   1 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:01+0000 |
|  4 |            2 |   0 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:02+0000 |
|  5 |            1 |   1 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:03+0000 |
|  6 |            1 |   0 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:04+0000 |
|  7 |            2 |   1 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:03+0000 |
|  8 |            2 |   0 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:04+0000 |
```

Query 1 should return the following result:

```
| Migration.id | Check_ID | OLD | OK |                             TIME |
|--------------|----------|-----|----|----------------------------------|
|      1       |     5    |   1 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:03+0000 |
|      2       |     7    |   1 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:03+0000 |
```

Query 1 should return the following result:

```
| Migration.id | Check_ID | OLD | OK |                             TIME |
|--------------|----------|-----|----|----------------------------------|
|      1       |     6    |   0 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:04+0000 |
|      2       |     8    |   0 |  1 | September, 22 2014 12:00:04+0000 |
```

I tried to solve it with a max in a subquery, but then I lose the information about `checks.ok` and check.time.

```sql
SELECT eq.id, (SELECT max(checks.id) FROM checks WHERE checks.migration_id = eq.id and checks.old = 't') AS latest FROM  migrations eq;
SELECT eq.id, (SELECT max(checks.id) FROM checks WHERE checks.migration_id = eq.id and checks.old = 'f') AS latest FROM  migrations eq;
```

(I know that I get `max(id)` instead of `max(time)`.)

In Rails I tried to fetch for each Migration the latest Record which resulted in the 1+n Problem. I'm not able to include all Checks because there are way to much of them.

Comment: Very nice job for a first question! The fiddle is especially welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **simple** solution with the Postgres specific `DISTINCT ON`:

**Query 1** ("for each migration the check with the biggest `time` where `old` is true"):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (migration_id)
       migration_id, id AS check_id, old, ok, time
FROM   checks
WHERE  old
ORDER  BY migration_id, time DESC;
```

Invert the the `WHERE` condition for **Query 2**:

```
...
WHERE  NOT old
...
```

Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

But if you want better read **performance** with big tables, use `JOIN LATERAL` (Postgres 9.2+, standard SQL), building on a multicolumn index like:

```
CREATE INDEX checks_special_idx ON checks(old, migration_id, time DESC);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT m.id AS migration_id
     , c.id AS check_id, c.old, c.ok, c.time
FROM   migrations m
-- FROM   (SELECT id FROM migrations LIMIT 150) m
JOIN   LATERAL (
     SELECT id, old, ok, time
     FROM   checks
     WHERE  migration_id = m.id
     AND    old
     ORDER  BY time DESC
     LIMIT  1
     ) c ON TRUE;
```

Switch the condition on `old` again for query 2.
For an unspecified "maximum of 150 migrations", use the commented alternative line.

Details:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/39e6e/2)

Aside: don't use "time" as identifier. It's a [reserved word in standard SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and a basic type name in Postgres.

Comment: Hi Erwin
It took me some time to implement solution 2 and test it but now it works perfect and fast. Since I already had indexes, the performance impact in changing the time index from normal to DESC was not measureable in my case. (Didn't write that)
I forgot to say that I want also migrations without checks, I made it by switching to left lateral join. 
My total querytime went down from 4 seconds to some milliseconds. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fabian: Nice. Yes, index scan backwards is almost as fast as forward. Did you also try the `DISTINCT ON` query for performance comparison?